# How to get RSSI of a connected BluetoothLEDevice in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I want to get the RSSI value of a `BluetoothLEDevice` which has already been connected by my program. So `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` doesn't work because the device no longer advertise after connected.
I have also tried `DeviceInformation.Properties["System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength"]` but the value never update. Is there any way to get the current RSSI value of a connected `BluetoothLEDevice`?

Comment: After connection to device Win 10 stores latest RSSI received from device during advertising. Use AdvertisementWatcher to get RSSI.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko But my device doesn't advertise after connected. I need to get the real time RSSI after connected.

Comment: Hello @RickyMo , the received signal strength indicator (RSSI) of Bluetooth is a dynamic value, which is updated with the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received` event. It will not be updated until new data is received.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Do you mean that there is no way to get the RSSI of a connected device?

Comment: Hello @RickyMo , when the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received` event is triggered, the event parameter contains the corresponding RSSI value ([RawSignalStrengthInDBm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementreceivedeventargs.rawsignalstrengthindbm?view=winrt-19041)). But currently the value will only be updated when the event is triggered.

Comment: If your device is not advertising after connect you can not get updated RSSI.

Comment: Interesting. I know android can request the RSSI of a connected device even it is not advertising. Is that a windows limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way currently to get connected RSSI on Windows. We are aware of the request by developers to implement connected RSSI, however it's not currently implemented and still in our backlog.